# Impossible to use ruby csv into app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-5

Trying to use the ruby included csv libary.

```
2.5.1 :001 > CSV
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant CSV, expected /home/xxxx/app/lib/csv.rb to define it)
2.5.1 :002 > ::CSV
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):2
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant CSV, expected /home/XXXX/app/lib/csv.rb to define it)
```

`require` just returns false.

```
2.5.1 :003 > require 'csv'
 => false
```

How can I use the default csv libary of ruby in my rails 5 app?

Comment: Do you have a file app/lib/csv.rb? Which does not declare anything named `CSV`? Rename it. It confuses rails' autoloader.

Comment: ^^ This. And in addition, rails conventions work much better if *all* filenames match the class/module that they contain. So if `app/lib/csv.rb` actualy contains something of value, rename the file to match that class/module name.

Comment: I am so stupid.... yeh had the `csv.rb` in my app lib folder -.-